# how to pass information from Objective-c's viewcontroller to a Swift storyboard

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I started to work in a project which was already started in ObjectiveC and without Storyboard. I'm making the new sections in Swift and with Storyboard, but now I'm having a problem when I try to pass information (an UIImage) to my storyboard's controllers.
This is how I go to the ViewControllers:

```
-(void)expenseCamera:(VOCCustomCameraVC *)camera didFinishPickImage:(UIImage *)
                       image imageCreated:(NSString *)imageCreated 
                       fileName:(NSString *)fileName {

    [camera dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];

         UIStoryboard *addExpenseStoryboard = [UIStoryboard 
                                             storyboardWithName:@"addExpense" bundle:nil];
         CreateExpenseVC *createExpenseVC = [addExpenseStoryboard 
         instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"expenseNavController"];
         UIImage *compressedImage = [UIImage compressImage: image];
         createExpenseVC.expenseImage = compressedImage; // It crashes here





    //createExpenseVC.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController: createExpenseVC animated: YES completion: nil];
    CFRunLoopWakeUp(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
}
```

If I take out the `createExpenseVC.expenseImage = compressedImage` everything goes well, but when I try to pass the image I get this error:

```
SIGABRT *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[YourApp.CustomNavController setExpenseImage:]: unrecognized selector
 sent to instance 0x12e09b200'
```

The destination viewController starts this way

```
@objcMembers class CreateExpenseVC: UIViewController {


   /* ---- IBOutlets ---- */
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var backButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @objc var expenseImage: UIImage?
```

And in the containerView I show another viewController where I pretend to show the image.

I tried to change the code I use to navigate to this

```
CreateExpenseVC * createExpenseVC = [[CreateExpenseVC alloc] init];
```

But it also crashes because (I think) it's not instantiating the Storyboard and therefore not recognizing all the IBOutlets and so on...

So how can I pass information like this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: where does "CustomNavController" come from? Your code doesn't show this

Comment: Unrelated to your question: I would honestly just throw away the old ObjC code that is not storyboard based.  It is an absolute waste of time.  It takes minutes to make a perfect modern storyboard for a given scene.  (Particularly since it looks like you are dealing with Cameras, just throw away the old ObjC code.  Waste of time.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to replicate your problem with the way you have implemented and it worked fine for me.

But your error said, that [YourApp.CustomNavController setExpenseImage:] is not implemented. That means your view controller is embedded inside a navigation controller.
And you are trying to get navigation controller by this code

```
[addExpenseStoryboard 
     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"expenseNavController"]
```

so your createExpenseVC is actually of type Navigation controller and not CreateExpenseViewController.

And that is why it doesn't get the expenseImage.

That is where your problem lies

Here is what you can do..

```
UIStoryboard *addExpenseStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"CreateExpense" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [addExpenseStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ExpenseNavC"];
CreateExpenseViewController *createExpenseVC = navController.viewControllers[0];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"383975"];

createExpenseVC.expenseImage = image;
[self presentViewController: navController animated: YES completion: nil];
```

Comment: Ohh I see, if I make the navigation directly to the viewController it works, but then I lose the navigationBar which I need. CreateExpenseVC is embedded in CustomNavController by storyboard, so in the code of CustomNavController I have only some code to set up the view...

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with this issue, I would check multiple things.

- Is storyboard ID assigned?
- Is the correct UIViewController class assigned?
- Is the UIViewController has view outlet?

Check these screenshot for a visual guide:

[View controller identify inspector screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaHFm.png)

[View controller view outlet screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxRLk.png)

Comment: if I don't try to pass any data it makes the navigation well. It loads the navController and the first viewController set to that navigation. The problem comes when I try to pass some data to the viewController because of the navController

Comment: You can try putting the UINavigationController on top of the current controller, then instead of `[self presentViewController: createExpenseVC animated: YES completion: nil];`, use `[navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:true];`.